# Replace characters in a Unix text file without line break

Tags: unix, text, replace

I would like to replace certain characters in a Unix file which does not have any line break.
I tried to use sed, but since there is no line break in the file, I got a zero byte output file.

sed 's/FORMS=11111/FORMS=22222/g' file.txt > out.txt

I do not have the bbe command. Could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: How long is the line? Can you show it to us?

Comment: The text file could be hundreds of Kilo Byte large, but does not contain line break in it.

Comment: The line may be too long for sed to handle properly. I'd probably write some C++ for this.

Comment: The text file supposed to have fix length lines in it, but for some reasons, the line breaks are gone. For example, if the text file is 1000 byte big and the lines are supposed to be 100 characters, then there are 10 lines in the text file without line breaks

Comment: Do you need to replace a characters or a strings? If the characters only, try `tr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said :

> The text file supposed to have fix length lines in it, but for some reasons, the line breaks are gone.

So you can use `fold` command to wrap text into at certain size and then run `sed` over the generated lines:

```
cat file.txt | fold -w <size> | sed ...
```

Comment: The sed command works, but the output file contains line breaks which I do not want

Comment: You can use `tr -d '\n'` or `paste -sd ''` to join lines into a single line.